# missing $args parameter for wordpress widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I am actually learning wordpress plugin development by following a tutorial at code.tutsplus.com

At this point i m stucked as from where the function will get $args param in below function

```
function widget_coming_next($args) {
  extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
  echo $before_widget;
  list_upcoming_posts();
  echo $after_widget;
}
```

the above function is simple wrapping by function list_upcoming_posts(); but still i don't see anywhere in the tutorial that this function is getting $args when its being called.

Below is how the function is called

```
function widget_coming_next_init() {
  wp_register_sidebar_widget(COMING_NEXT_WIDGET_ID, 
    __('Coming Next'), 'widget_coming_next');
}

// Register widget to WordPress
add_action("plugins_loaded", "widget_coming_next_init");
```

Everything else is clear to me but i am unable to continue the lesson because of lack of understanding. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Which tutorial are you following? Do you have a link?

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/anatomy-of-a-wordpress-plugin--net-2127 this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd param of `wp_register_sidebar_widget()` is a callback function which is run when the widget is called. The callback function takes the form:

```
function my_output_callback_function( $args, $params ){ ... }
```

In your case, the callback function is your `widget_coming_next()` function. `$args` will be an array of various values.

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_sidebar_widget

Comment: yeah i am trying this but i am getting empty values for various variables in twentyforteen theme

Comment: my question actually was how $args getting values ? Is this done by wordpress itself ? if i change $args to $xyz will it be same ?

Comment: The `$args` array contains stuff like `widget_id`, `widget_name` and also the argument array values from the `register_sidebars()` function such as `before_widget` and `before_title`. See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_sidebar_widget#Output_Callback_Function_Parameters_Format) for more info

Comment: I have read these docs. If i say that the $args is passed on run time by wordpress itself. M i right ?

Comment: Looking at the tutorial, `widget_coming_next_init()` is hooked to the `plugins_loaded` action so it will all happen at the point at which that action fires.